# How many iterative attacks can an Eidolon with a two-handed weapon make?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, summoner, multiattack

I'm experienced with RPG's but this is my first run of Pathfinder.

I elected to play a summoner who's Eidolon wield a greatsword. I've heard of this class's supposed "brokenness" so I elected to eschew the natural attacks with multiple arms style of Eidolon and go for a more "summoned angel" flavor.

My question is derived from my understanding of the BAB and iterative rules for Eidolon. I can see that in the Eidolon's BAB table, it doesn't indicate iterative attacks with the BAB for manufactured weapons such as +6/+1, but specifies a daily amount of natural attacks it can make (which, to be honest, I'm still confused on what the to-hit modifiers on 3 consecutive natural attacks would be as well.)

Can a greatsword-wielding Eidolon make iterative attacks with a two-handed weapon at all? I'd really enjoy the flavor of an summoned angel, but nonetheless I'll be bummed if I'm not allowed to make consecutive attacks at higher levels if my Eidolon wields a two-handed sword.

Comment: Do you plan on handing your eidolon the greatsword everytime its summoned or are you considering it a homebrewed evolution?

Comment: I decided to go synthesist, the flavor was too cool for me. I may request some homebrewed evolutions from my GM given that most of the ones available favor and buff natural attacks and I'm not keen on using them. Going for a demure priest who is granted an angelic suit of armor from his deity.

Answer (score 6):

The eidolon totally gets iterative attacks with a manufactured weapon when its base attack bonus is +6 or higher. From [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Base-Attack-Bonus-BAB-)...

> **Base Attack Bonus (BAB):** Each creature has a base attack bonus and it represents its skill in combat. As a character gains levels or Hit Dice, his base attack bonus improves. When a creature's base attack bonus reaches +6, +11, or +16, he receives an additional attack in combat when he takes a full-attack action (which is one type of full-round action—see Combat).

...and [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Attack-Bonus)...

> **Base Attack Bonus:** A base attack bonus is an attack roll bonus derived from character class and level or creature type and Hit Dice (or combination's thereof). Base attack bonuses increase at different rates for different character classes and creature types. A second attack is gained when a base attack bonus reaches +6, a third with a base attack bonus of +11 or higher, and a fourth with a base attack bonus of +16 or higher. Base attack bonuses gained from different sources, such as when a character is a multiclass character, stack.

Undoubtedly there are edge cases wherein a creature using a manufactured weapons *doesn't* get iterative attacks, but such a feature would be noted among the creature's abilities.

---

Natural weapons for the most part don't yield iterative attacks. Instead, the creature uses one natural weapon during a standard attack, or *all* its natural weapons on a full attack, with some natural weapons designated primary and other natural weapons designated secondary as per this [chart](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Natural-Attacks); secondary natural weapon attacks suffer a -5 penalty to attack rolls and the damage bonus from the creature's Strength score is halved.

A creature wielding a manufactured weapon that also possesses natural weapons who takes the full attack action attacks with his manufactured weapon normally (including iterative attacks due to base attack bonus and usual damage bonus due to Strength) and can *also* make natural weapon attacks with any natural weapons not occupied with the manufactured weapon, but all such natural weapon attacks are considered secondary, suffering a -5 penalty to attack rolls and the damage bonus from the creature's Strength score is halved.

A cursory search should reveal questions probing the use of natural weapons in *Pathfinder* and its precursors and get answers that go into staggering detail.